# Pytorch: convolve a sample with a specific filter

Tags: keras, pytorch, convolution

Given a batch of samples, I would like to convolve each of them with different filters. I have implemented the idea with keras and the code works:

```
import keras.backend as K

def single_conv(tupl):
    inp, kernel = tupl
    outputs = K.conv1d(inp, kernel, padding='same')
    return outputs

# inputs and filters are given in some way
res = K.squeeze(K.map_fn(single_conv, (inputs, filters), dtype=K.floatx()), axis=1)
```

Is there any way to do this with pytorch?

Comment: Check this: https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/fast-way-to-use-map-in-pytorch/70814/13

Comment: Yeah I found the same post, but I cannot find a appropriate solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
import torch.nn as nn
import torch

conv2d = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=3, out_channels=3, kernel_size=3)
inp = torch.ones((1, 3, 5, 5))
conv2d.weight = nn.Parameter(torch.ones((3, 3, 3, 3))) # You can set anything you want.
model = nn.Sequential(conv2d)
res = model(inp)
print(res.shape)
# print(res)
```

You can convolve it with whatever filter you want.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But what I demand is that each sample can be convolved with a specific filter. For example, given 10 samples, there should be 10 filters, and each of them takes care of a sample.